# Is there any point to statistical analysis with Minesweeper?

Tags: probability

I've done some rough figures re: the impasse you encounter when you are forced to guess. I could supply the figures, but what it boils down to is: The mines simply are not stationary under the blue field. My "guess" percentage is so far below statistical probability (aggregating about 28% of random!) that the only rational conclusion is that the game algorithm is picking winners and losers, probably base on prior win/loss % and your play frequency.

Comment: Code your own version of minesweeper, where you know that the code isn't cheating, and check if your guess percentage significantly increases ...